# MVC .NET razor DropDownList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-select

I cannot link dropdownlist to my model in the view.
I have the error message:
The ViewData item that has the key 'title' is of type 'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable
with the following code:

```
public class FareCustomer
{
    [Required]
    public int title { get; set; }
```

My controller:

```
List<SelectListItem> titleList = new List<SelectListItem>();
titleList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Non renseigné", Value = "0" });
titleList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Monsieur", Value = "1" });
titleList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Madame", Value = "2" });
titleList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Mademoiselle", Value = "3" });
ViewBag.title = titleList;
//Create a new customer
FareCustomer fareCustomer = new FareCustomer();
fareCustomer.title = 1;
return View("CreateAccount", fareCustomer);
```

My view 'CreateAccount'

```
@model PocFareWebNet.Models.FareCustomer
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    @Html.DropDownList("title")
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</fieldset>
}
```

I tried to apply what is described here: [Using the DropDownList Helper with ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc)
but obviously I missed something.

Comment: Did you get the error after posting the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my issue.
I used the view generated by Visual Studio and it already defines ViewBag.Title

```
@model PocFareWebNet.Models.FareCustomer
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "CreateAccount";
}
```

This is why the error says the type is string and cannot be converted to IEnumerable.

It seems razor is not case sensitive: The controller set ViewBag.title but the view set ViewBag.Title and overwrites ViewBag.title coming from the controller.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Try casting to IEnumarable and use model based helper

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.title,((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.title))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.title, (SelectList)ViewBag.title)
```

The first argument will be receiving your selected value.

Comment: The error is now: Cannot convert type 'string' to 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList'

Comment: It seems that your ViewBag.title is not setted as your List<SelectListItem>, can you show more code on the controller side (both GET and POST actions) ?

Comment: There's another possibility : `ViewBag.Title` is probably used in your layout or a parent view, as the title of the page, and there's a chance that your `List<SelectListItem>` gets overriden somewhere before getting to your drop down list. You can either search for other usages of `ViewBag.Title`, or rename "Title" to something more specific, like `ViewBag.FareCustomerTitleList`. You can also verify it by displaying `ViewBag.title`'s current value in your view.